# How to Add Order ID & Order Item Quantity to a Notification Email for Woocommerce Gravity Forms Product Add-Ons Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

The **Woocommerce Gravity Forms Product Add-Ons** plugin creates entries and connects them with an order, but it looks like you can't add Order ID and Product Quantity to the GravityForms Notification from the box.

Perhaps the answer will be helpful for someone.

P.S. It will be good if before dislike it, you write a comment about why?

Answer (score 2):

Two filters. We add custom tags to GravityForms GUI and process them. After that we can add them here Admin ---> GravityForms ---> A form ---> Settings ---> Notification ---> Message field.

```
/**
 * Add custom tags with Order ID & Order Item Quantity to the GravityForm notification.
 *
 * @link https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_replace_merge_tags/
 * @see /plugins/woocommerce-gravityforms-product-addons/inc/gravityforms-product-addons-entry.php
 */
function woo_gform_pre_replace_merge_tags( $text, $form, $entry, $url_encode, $esc_html, $nl2br, $format ) {
$order_number_tag        = '{order_number}';
$order_item_quantity_tag = '{order_item_quantity}';

/*
 * An WC Order contains some Items (products).
 * One WC Order Item produces one GForm Entry.
 * GForm performs email notification. We need Order ID & Product Amount into the notification.
 */
if ( isset( $entry['id'] ) && ! empty( $form ) ) {
    $order_id            = gform_get_meta( $entry['id'], 'woocommerce_order_number' );
    $order_item_id       = gform_get_meta( $entry['id'], 'woocommerce_order_item_number' );
    $order_item_quantity = wc_get_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, '_qty', true );

    // The {order_number} tag
    if ( strpos( $text, $order_number_tag ) !== false ) {
        $text = str_replace( $order_number_tag, $order_id, $text );
    }

    // The {order_item_quantity} tag
    if ( strpos( $text, $order_item_quantity_tag ) !== false ) {
        $text = str_replace( $order_item_quantity_tag, $order_item_quantity, $text );
    }
  }

  return $text;
}

add_filter( 'gform_pre_replace_merge_tags', 'woo_gform_pre_replace_merge_tags', 10, 7 );


/**
 * Add custom tags in the GravityForm UI.
 *
 * @see woo_gform_pre_replace_merge_tags()
 */
function woo_add_custom_merge_tags( $merge_tags, $form_id, $fields, $element_id ) {
$merge_tags[] = [
    'label' => esc_html__( 'Order Number', 'textdomain' ),
    'tag'   => '{order_number}'
];
$merge_tags[] = [
    'label' => esc_html__( 'Order Item Quantity', 'textdomain' ),
    'tag'   => '{order_item_quantity}'
];

  return $merge_tags;
}

add_filter( 'gform_custom_merge_tags', 'woo_add_custom_merge_tags', 10, 4 );
```